# Listview Layout Template Error

Tags: asp.net, listview, layout, itemtemplate

I am querying a column from my db and when I test the query with the sqldatasource the numbers shows up fine. However, when I run the application, all the numbers in the column add two zeros at the end of it.

For example,

```
Instead of 1 it is 100
Instead of 2 it is 200
```

I dont know what the cause of this may be.

Here is my LayoutTemplate:

```
<LayoutTemplate>

        <table runat="server">
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server">
                    <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="1" style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                        <tr runat="server" style="background-color: #E0FFFF;color: #333333; ">

                            <th runat="server"></th>
                            <th runat="server"> FormTitle</th>
                            <th runat="server">FormSection</th>
                            <th runat="server">SubSection</th>
                            <th runat="server">SectionItem</th>
                            <th runat="server">SortOrder</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server" style="text-align: center;background-color: #5D7B9D;font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #FFFFFF">
                    <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PageSize="7">
                        <Fields>
                            <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True" ShowLastPageButton="True" />
                        </Fields>
                    </asp:DataPager>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </LayoutTemplate>
```

ItemTemplate:

```
        <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color: #E0FFFF;color: #333333;">
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="DeleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
                <asp:Button ID="EditButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="FormTitleLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FormTitle") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="FormSectionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FormSection") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="SubSectionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SubSection") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="SectionItemLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SectionItem") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="SortOrder" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SortOrder") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: What is the data type of the column in Database? Could you try like this `Eval("xxx", "{0:0.##})`?

Comment: @Win That did not work. I believe the data type is Int 32

Comment: @Win Actually the type is a smallint

Comment: I figured out issue problem was on my part. Thanks